# express can`t get query param from url

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express

I use `express` framework and `react` on front app for manage http request on node app. A have method :

```
app.get('/api/matches', async (req, res) =>  {
 console.log(req.originalUrl); // /api/matches/
 console.log(req.query); // {}
 ...
```

when I use url like `http://localhost:3000/matches?id=123` I expect to get `id` inside `req.query` object but instead I get empty `{}` object. Also I tried to check how `express` see url using `originUrl` object, its return without `query ?id=123`.

Comment: You are using `http://localhost:3000/matches?id=123`, instead of `http://localhost:3000/api/matches?id=123`. Is this a typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use your URL like `http://localhost:3000/api/matches/?id=123`. Notice that `api` word. This is because your GET route has `/api/matches` and request will look for path `/api/matches`. Doing that change will work for you. Then with that change you will be able to get `req.query` as `{id: 123}`

Comment: This is **not** correct with Express version `4.16.2`. I can successfully get query parameters whether I send the request with the last forward slash or without.

Comment: @Hkan edited my answer